# Weird syntax related to spread syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Recently I came across this code which was working fine until I updated babel dependencies.

```
const somefunc = ({ type }) => [
  ...type === 'image' && ['height'],
  'name',
  'text'
];
```

To make it work again I changed the code to:-

```
const somefunc = ({ type }) => [
  type === 'image' && 'height',
  'name',
  'text'
];
```

Now the problem is older syntax is used in many places in our code. Also, I unable to find this syntax anywhere on community or older version of ES or in babel transpilers.

Comment: `..type === 'image' && ['height'],` should mean "if `type` is equal to `'image'` then spread the array `['height']`". However, this doesn't seem like a good choice, since if `type` is *not* equal to `'image`, then you'd get an error, as the expression resolves to `...false` and you can't spread a boolean value. So, on one hand, it does seem like Babel is either not handling it correctly or is not configured correctly but on the other hand, the syntax you want to use is likely to lead to problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments this is a way to conditionally add items to array, however this code will not work if the condition is `false`. This can be fixed by using ternary operator:

```
const somefunc = ({ type }) => [
  ...type === 'image' ? ['height'] : [],
  'name',
  'text'
];
```

Also your second option won't work correctly either, since it will add `false` to the array in case the condition is `false`.